# I need convert XML format to csv or xlsx with bash script

Tags: bash, scripts, libreoffice, cron

I have troubles with converting XML file to csv, .xls, .xlsx, .xlst, .ods, .ots  I am using ubuntu server command line.
I need change supplier xml file to friendly prestashop importing file. 
So, i need convert xml with separators. And i need do this with bash script, to do automatically.

I am getting something like this -

```
<p><strong>Battery</strong><br,/>,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
<attribute,"title=""water-resistance""><![CDATA[IP67]]></attribute>",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

This , going till line end. Impossible to use. If i converting without ,, i getting same xml file, just in csv. I mean nothing has changed.

I already trying without success- ssconvert, libreoffice, xml2 and unoconv.

Maybe someone can tell me ubuntu command how to fix it... Trying all day.

In this picture is what exactly i need https://zoo.ogi.lt/xml.JPG

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Does it need to *specifically* be a bash script? Or will any kind of script work? A python script would be quite easy to knock together.

Comment: Wow, thanks for fast respond. If we can run this with crontab, we can try this...